# Why do SO blog messages appear on unrelated SE sites?

Tags: discussion, blog

I'm just curious, but when using the Pets SE I noticed that the announcement

> BLOG: You Can Now Download Stack Overflow’s 2016 Developer Survey Data

appeared.

I realize that SE is strongly rooted in SO, but I presume we want to continue fostering non-programming communities in non-programming SE sites. So, I'm curious why this shows up there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because that's the company blog, not just Stack Overflow blog.

The company name used to be Stack Exchange in the past,  but [changed (back) to Stack Overflow in September 2015](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/).

Thus, the company blog has the domain of stackoverflow.com, however it contains blog posts about the whole company,  e.g.

- [Re-introducing Data Explorer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/06/learn-more-about-your-site-with-the-se-data-explorer-heres-how/) (Can be used for all sites)
- [Non-profit good things done by the company](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/05/stack-overflow-participating-in-white-house-foster-care-and-technology-hackathon/)
- [Welcoming new employees](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/05/welcoming-stack-overflows-new-cmo-adrianna-burrows/)

...and more.